# How can I get the connection string for an SQL Express database listed in LINQPad?

Tags: database, database-connection, connection-string, linqpad

Is there an easy way to get the connection string of a database listed in the connection window of LINQPad (other than using the object explorer of Visual Studio)?

Comment: It would help if you say what you've already tried. But most likely you simply need to specify the server as `<machinename>\` without an instance name as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010735/connect-linqpad-to-remote-sql-sever

Comment: Is the connection working? If so then try `this.Connection.ConnectionString.Dump();`

Comment: Thanks, this.Connection.ConnectionString works.

Answer (score 17):

Making [sgmoore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125759/sgmoore)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360921/how-can-i-get-the-connection-string-for-an-sql-express-database-listed-in-linqpa/#comment-39576786) into an answer:

try `this.Connection.ConnectionString.Dump();`

Comment: I might be doing something wrong, but I have tried this against an OData connection in LinqPad and only get an error : CS1061 'UserQuery' does not contain a definition for 'Connection' and no extension method 'Connection' accepting a first argument of type 'UserQuery' could be found (press F4 to add a using directive or assembly reference).

I have tried all available languages - anyone any ideas?

Comment: this.Connection only exists if you've selected a connection in the Connection dropdown at the top of Linqpad's editor window.

Comment: It is `this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString` at least in version 5.36

Answer (score 4):

In LinqPad 5 if your **Language** dropdown is set to *C# Program* and you have a database selected in the **Connection** dropdown, then you can get your string using

```
string c = LINQPad.Util.CurrentDataContext.Connection.ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 0):

In LinqPad7 you do:

```
this.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString
```

This will show you the connection string.

Comment: I have to use this `this.Database.GetConnectionString()`. I'm using EF Core 6 provider.

Comment: I use LinqPad7, but i can't  find this.Database !!  when i use sql server it marked red. Do you know why?