# How Can I connect to this OData Feed in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, odata, connection-string

I have access to a corporate OData feed, but I can only to connect to it from specific applications. (PowerBI, Excel and LinqPad)

The connection details I have, are a URL and Basic Auth Username and Password. However, I know the feed is stored in Azure (not sure which part...) and I think I need some other kind of Authentication to connect.

I am using the latest version of SQL Data Tools and Visual Studio 2015 U2. I have tried using the built in OData connection manager with all of the possible Auth Types and the user/pass i was given with no luck. (Windows Auth, Basic Auth, Microsoft Dynamics AX Online, Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online, Microsoft Online Services)

What confuses me, is why it works fine in LinqPad, Excel and PowerBI but i can't get SSIS to connect. Which i need for data automation!

I have attempted to get the connection string from LinqPad using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360921/how-can-i-get-the-connection-string-for-an-sql-express-database-listed-in-linqpa/) but I get an error about UserQuery not having a property Connection. Which may be something to do with Entity Framework?

Does anyone know any tips or tricks to get this working?

Comment: Most likely you dont have the latest version of Odata. A newer version of Odata came out recently (dont recall the date) and I was able to use that to fetch data from Sharepoint sites into our data servers using SSIS.

Comment: Thanks @rvphx, is the v4 OData standard you are referring to? I will do a bit of searching for this.